# htaccess redirect and db connection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to temporary move a website AAAA.AA to a different page BBBB.BB (preferably hiding BBBB.BB so people won't notice a URL change), which is much cleaner and simpler, whilst we do some more restyling work on AAAA.AA. However there are several db connections from other websites to AAAA.AA.

Is there a clean way to keep the db connections live whilst redirecting the view on BBBB.BB? I've tried to use a frame on AAAA.AA, but BBBB.BB doesn't allow me to do that.

I think therefore that maybe a solution can be found working with the .htaccess file. A 302 redirection might pose problems, but what about a the Rewrite rule? I've read it is not a redirect and everything happens on the server-side. Would that be ok for db connections from other sites?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to change the destination of the connection with:

```
RewriteRule ^/AAAA.AA /BBBB.BB (for a page)
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/AAAA.AA/(.*)$ /BBBB.BB/$1 (for part of a directory path)
```

Note: That assumes that AAAA.AA is a page or part of a directory path, not a whole URL. If it's a URL, you would need a somewhat different RewriteRule.

This is done in Apache. If someone makes a DB connection they are not going through Apache and, so, will not get a rewrite.